# How to unloack HR database in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, database-schema, unlock

i tried downloading hr schema from oracle's site, it doesnt worked for me.
accessing oracle's HR account, we need to unlock HR account

Answer (score 0):

[![ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK

ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4lUC.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4lUC.png)